# Mvc C# upload pdf ，have error message (HTTP 404)，but file are already upload to the designated path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I want to wirte Mvc C# upload pdf，but have some difficulties.
When I upload file，have error message (HTTP 404)，
but file are already upload to the  designated path.
How can I solve it ? thanks.

error message：

- Server Error in '/' occurs app.
- Resource not found.Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are
  looking for (or one of dependence) may have removed the name has
  changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
- Please review the following URL, and make sure it's spelled
  correctly. URL requested: / MakeUpExam / Upload

code：

controller：

```
  public ActionResult MakeUpExam()
    {
        List<TesrModel> TesrModel = new List<TesrModel>();
            using (SqlConnection Coon = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                Coon.Open();

                SqlCommand commandExamInfo = new SqlCommand();
                using (commandExamInfo = new SqlCommand(@"select * from aaa where bbb=@bbb", Coon)) commandExamInfo.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bbb", "123"));
                {
                    commandExamInfo.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataReader reader;
                    reader = commandExamInfo.ExecuteReader();
                    {
                        if (reader.FieldCount != 0)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                TesrModel.Add(
                                  new TesrModel()
                                  {
                                      a = reader["a"].ToString(),
                                      b = reader["b"].ToString(),
                                      c = reader["c"].ToString(),
                                  });
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        return View(TesrModel);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        using (SqlConnection Coon = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            Coon.Open();
            using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select ccc from ddd where eee=@eee and fff= @fff", Coon))
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@eee", "aaa"));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fff", "bbb"));
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    if (file.ContentLength <= 1042880)
                    {
                        if (file.ContentType == "pdf" || file.ContentType== "application/pdf")
                        {
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            var Newfilename = fileName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                            var path = Path.Combine(@"D:\data", Newfilename);
                            file.SaveAs(path);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.Message  = "msut pdf file";
                        }

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "file too large";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "please select file, thanks.";
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Upload");
    }
}}
```

View

```html
@model IEnumerable<MakeUpExam.Models.TesrModel>
<h2>Upload</h2>


<table class="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.a)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.b)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.c)
        </th>
        <th>
            upload file
        </th>
        <th>
            upload  time
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.a)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.b)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.c)
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="@Url.Action("Upload")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file">Filename:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><input type="submit" value="upload file" />
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Models

```
public class testModel
{
    public string a{ get; set; }
    public string b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In addition to not appearing to have a GET method for `Upload()`, you code is not going to work correctly and you need to use the `Server.MapPath()` method to save you files so they can be retrieved (refer [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/) for a typical example

Comment: And do not use `ViewBag` for your error messages (they will be discarded as soon as you redirect) - add a `ModelState` error and return the view. Highly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand how to work with forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your post to `Upload`, you try to redirect to `Upload` (`return RedirectToAction("Upload");`).

When we look at your controller, you have no HttpGet Action that is called `Upload`. You probably want to redirect somewhere else after the upload.

Comment: Yes，I want to redirect.

Comment: I create a new view to redirect